# Laravel 5.4 proper way to store Locale setLocale()

Tags: laravel, locale

I need to know. What is the proper way to store Locale for user. If for each users' request I change the language by

```
    App::setLocale($newLocale);
```

Would not it change language for my whole project and for other requests as well? I mean when one user changes language it will be used as default for other users.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you set `App::setLocale()` in for example in your `AppServiceProvider.php`, it would change for all the users.

You could create a middleware for this. Something like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        app()->setLocale($request->user()->getLocale());

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

(You need to create a `getLocale()` method on the User model for this to work.)

And then in your `Kernel.php` create a middleware group for `auth`:

```
'auth' => [
    \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale::class,
],
```

And remove the `auth` from the `$routeMiddleware` array (in your `Kernel.php`).

Now on every route that uses the `auth` middleware, you will set the Locale of your Laravel application for each user.

Comment: Thank you, This is the approach that I want!

Comment: `app()->getLocale()` and `app()->setLocale('en')` worked for me in controller file also. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem with a controller, middleware, and with session.
This worked for me well, hope it helps you.

**Handle the user request via the controller:**

Simply set the language to the users session.

```
     /**
     * Locale switcher
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Routing\Redirector
     */
    public function switchLocale(Request $request)
    {
        if (!empty($request->userLocale)) {
             Session::put('locale', $request->userLocale);
        }
        return redirect($request->header("referer"));
    }
```

**Route to switch locale:**

```
Route::post('translations/switchLocale}', ['as' => 'translations.switch', 'uses' => 'Translation\TranslationController@switchLocale']);
```

**Middleware to handle the required settings:**

In the Middleware check the user's session for the language setting, if its pereset set it.

```
/**
 * @param $request
 * @param Closure $next
 * @param null $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
   if (Session::has('locale')) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
   }
}
```

**Lastly the switching form:**

```
{!! Form::open(["route" => "translations.switch", "id" => "sideBarLocaleSelectorForm"]) !!}
{!! Form::select("userLocale", $languages, Session::get("locale")) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<script>
    $(document).on("change", "select", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When someone loads your website it uses the default which is set in the config file.

> The default language for your application is stored in the config/app.php configuration file.

Using the `App::setLocale()` method would only change for a specific user which I assume would be set in the session, the config file value would not be altered.

> You may also change the active language at runtime using the setLocale method on the App facade

You could see this in action yourself by opening your website in two different browsers (as they would be using two different sessions) then changing the locale in one and seeing the default load in the other.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#introduction

Comment: Hey there. I'm try to do getLocal and setLocal within a middleware. I have folders like en,ru,tr these are supposed to be the names of the languages that the getlocal should give am I right?

Comment: @Nikonah Yep I think so, best to review the docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#introduction

Answer (score 1):

If still anyone facing problem, here is a sollution. Here **X-Language** is coming with the request.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!Session::get('locale')) {
            Session::put('locale', $request->header('X-Language'));
        }
        App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a middleware like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SetLocale
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (auth()->check() && $languageId = auth()->user()->language_id) {
            $locale = Language::find($languageId)->locale;
            app()->setLocale($locale);
        }
        
        if ($request->lang) {
            app()->setLocale($request->lang);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same problem, the locale was changing in session but not in config. So have checked the session's locale in every blade and controller and set the default the language instant from there, here is the code on my blade file

```
@php
if(\Session::get('locale') == 'en') 
    \App::setLocale('en');
else                                
    \App::setLocale('bn');
```

@endphp

Hope it will help you

Comment: I think that it is really a bad idea to set the locale from a blade file. Nobody would expect it to have such a side effect.

Comment: Actually i didn't got any other suitable solution, if you suggest something with an example that would help us