# redirect()->back() is not working when I switch another language

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I used this way for localization in laravel 5.1, It is working fine. Now I am facing translation text is not working with `return redirect()->back()` in laravel 5.5.

```
Route::get('lang/{locale}', function ($locale) {
  \App::setLocale($locale);
  \Session::put('langKey', $locale);
  // return redirect()->back();
  return view('welcome');
});
```

It works well if I use `return view('welcome')`, but does not work for `redirect()`.

The code from *welcome.blade.php* is

```
<ul>
   @if(App::isLocale('en'))
    <li><a href="{{url('/lang/my')}}">ျမန္မာ</a></li>
   @else
    <li><a href="{{url('/lang/en')}}">English</a></li>
   @endif
</ul>    

App -> {{ app()->getLocale() }}
<br>
Session -> {{Session::get('langKey')}}

<br>
@lang('test.home')
```

Screenshot using redirect back:

[image: X]

Screenshot using return view - 1:

[image: X]

Screenshot using return view - 2:

[image: X]

Comment: I just have made simple 2 routes, in second route I called setLocale and after return redirect back. It's working for me. Probably there is some another problem..

Comment: And could you please specify what exactly in not working.. because "not worked for redirect()" it is not very informative

Comment: Hi Aleksandrs, I've already added screenshot for my question. Could you pls help :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45433877/laravel-5-4-proper-way-to-store-locale-setlocale

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Comment: how I understood, setLocale is working only for current request

Comment: Could you pls check the code from github https://github.com/ZinMarHtunRDN/testing_cms

Comment: https://github.com/ZinMarHtunRDN/TestTranslation I've been tested this laravel 5.1 project is working this way :('

Comment: first github is empty project, second without routes folder..

Comment: sorry, I use branch localization . https://github.com/ZinMarHtunRDN/testing_cms/tree/localization. second project is laravel 5.1 so that route.php is under app/Http https://github.com/ZinMarHtunRDN/TestTranslation/blob/master/app/Http/routes.php

Comment: I have sent link to stackoverflow, just implement 1 on possible solutions ;)

Comment: I don't understand why should we use the middleware to change locale.

Comment: Can you share me the way or reference(tutorial) for laravel 5.5 localization without changing url/route and not include locale uri. Meaning, I want to use www.mydomain.com, don't want to use like that www.mydomain.com/en.

Comment: I want to say "thank you" Aleksandrs. This is due to welcome page route. No need to use middleware

Comment: hmm, what was the problem with Route::get('/', function () { return view('welcome'); });  route?

Comment: It was working the route using Controller with function. My problem was the directly use of functon.